# How to return enums to list view from datatable?

Tags: c#, enums, return

I have a list to return data from database.

```
sampleditemlist.Add(new SampledItem() {
                        SampledItemID = row["SampledItemID"] == DBNull.Value ? 
                            0 : 
                            int.Parse(row["SampledItemID"].ToString()),
                        SerialNumber = row["SerialNumber"] == DBNull.Value ? 
                            "" : 
                            row["SerialNumber"].ToString(),

                    });
```

I have enum class as follows.

```
 public enum EnumSampledCategory
    {
        All = 1,
        Government_Sampling = 2,
        Sampling_In_Packaging = 3,
        Sampling_At_Warehouse = 4
    }
```

How can I use this `enum` for sampled category like

```
SampledItemID = row["SampledItemID"] == DBNull.Value ? 
    0 : 
    int.Parse(row["SampledItemID"].ToString())
```

?

Comment: What is a database type of the column "SampledItemID"?

Comment: how about enum ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert DataRow value to string and then parse it to integer, if database column is of type `Int`(my assumption), then `DataRow` has it as integer type, you only need to cast it, because DataRow returns values of type `object`.

If column allow `null` values, cast it to the nullable int. 
You can use extension method `.Field<T>`

When you get integer value you can cast to the enum type

```
var category = 
    (EnumSampledCategory)row.Field<int?>("SampledItemId").GetValueOrDefault();
```

For `string` types as well

```
var serialNumber = row.Field<string>("SerialNumber");
```

No need for DbNull check, `string` is reference type and have `null` value, so `null` will be returned  when value in DataRow is `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

this most be Helpful

```
 namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int id = 3;
            var s = (EnumSampledCategory)id; // s variable take this valie=>Sampling_In_Packaging 
        }
    }
    public enum EnumSampledCategory
    {
        All = 1,
        Government_Sampling = 2,
        Sampling_In_Packaging = 3,
        Sampling_At_Warehouse = 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum value can be saved as int or varchar or nvarchar in database. let consider enum is saved as int in database. Then you can cast it to get the enum type.

```
EnumSampledCategory sampledCategory= row["SampledItemId"] == DBNull.Value ? EnumType.None : (EnumType)(int)row["SampledItemId"];
```

So, just add in one more None in your enum as value 0 and use it as default value if the value is null in database.

Comment: I tried this. But it gives me an error " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Model.enum.EnumSampledCategory' to 'int'. An explicit conversion is exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's add value for `0`:

```
  public enum EnumSampledCategory
  {
      None                  = 0, // corresponds to null in RDBMS
      All                   = 1,
      Government_Sampling   = 2,
      Sampling_In_Packaging = 3,
      Sampling_At_Warehouse = 4
  }
```

If it's possible that a `SampledItem` can be *both* `Sampling_In_Packaging` and, say, `Government_Sampling` you may want to turn `enum` into *flagged* one:

```
  [Flags]
  public enum EnumSampledCategory
  {
      None                  = 0,
      Government_Sampling   = 1,
      Sampling_In_Packaging = 2,
      Sampling_At_Warehouse = 4,
      // All is combination of all other samplings: 1 | 2 | 4 == 7
      All = Government_Sampling | Sampling_In_Packaging | Sampling_At_Warehouse
  }
```

Then all you want is `Convert`:

```
  MySampledCategory = (EnumSampledCategory)Convert.ToInt32(
    row["SampledCategory"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : row["SampledCategory"]);
```